# jQuery Selector for ID containing colons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, escaping

I'm trying to select an element using jQuery 2.0 with an ID that contains two colons as follows:

```
<div id="container:divobj:1">My Div</div>
```

I am using a double back-slash to escape the colons:

```
alert($("#container\\:divobj\\:1").length());
```

Every time I try to run this code I get the error:

> Property 'length' of object [object Object] is not a function

I've setup a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/boggey79/wtfRY/) to illustrate.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? BTW I can't change the ID naming conventions as this is a user script running on a 3rd Party.

Comment: `;` is semicolon. `:` is colon.

Comment: It's `length` (a property), not `length()` (a method)

Comment: Oh dear, it's been a long day :/

Comment: Happens to all of us :p

Comment: I do that exact thing regularly.

Comment: I was so convinced something iffy was happening with the colons I missed the glaringly obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

length is not a method (*it's property*)

http://api.jquery.com/length/

```
alert($("#container\\:divobj\\:1").length);
```

Or jquery has a `size` method for that

http://api.jquery.com/size/ (*version deprecated: 1.8*)

```
alert($("#container\\:divobj\\:1").size());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/wtfRY/3/

Comment: Yep that's done the trick! I've used .length a million times...not sure how I missed this!

Answer (score 1):

The `length` *property* is not a function. It is... a property :)

You don't access properties with parenthesis at the end like you would with functions. The parenthesis are actually what executes the function.

You can simply use `.length` to get the number of elements.

On the flip side, should you attempt to execute a *function* without parenthesis at the end, it will simply return the function's definition.

For example:

```
var a = "STACK OVERFLOW";
console.log(a.toLowerCase); 
// output: function toLowerCase() { [native code] }
console.log(a.toLowerCase());
// output: "stack overflow";
```